# Spring boot - gradle Intellij Idea build and Jenkins build result is not same.

Tags: jenkins, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I spend lot of time to deploy spring boot application via jenkins. However I am keep failing.

In my local, executing gradle `bootRepackage` command to build a `jar` file in Intellij Idea and It is Ok to run `jar` file( with command `java -jar -Dspring.profile.active=user ABC.jar` )

So I register this command to Jenkins and send `jar` via `Publish Over SSH` with following steps.

1. invoke gradle script with `bootRepackage --stacktrace -x test --refresh-dependencies`
2. send jar file to server
3. execute with `java -jar -Dspring.profile.active=user ABC.jar`

The problem is some of autowired bean becomes null which has no problem in my local. Please review my build gradle script and give me some advices.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.1.RELEASE'
        springBootStarterVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
        infinispanVersion = '8.2.6.Final'
        coreVersion = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

jar {
    baseName = 'ABC'
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'net.ion.ice.Ice2Application')
    }
}

bootRepackage {
    withJarTask jar
    mainClass = 'net.ion.ice.Ice2Application'
}

war {
    baseName = 'ABC'
    version = "${coreVersion}"
    enabled = false
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'net.ion.ice.Ice2Application')
    }
}

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://my-repo.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'
        name 'my-repo'
    }

}

dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootStarterVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:${springBootStarterVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootStarterVersion}")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5+')
    compile('commons-net:commons-net:3.4+')
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.5+')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.6+')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.6+')

    // yml parser
    compile ('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.8.9')

    compile('ch.qos.logback:logback-access:1.2.3')
    compile('net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:4.8+')

    compile ("org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.1")

    compile("org.infinispan:infinispan-embedded:${infinispanVersion}")
    compile("org.infinispan:infinispan-query:${infinispanVersion}")
    compile('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0')

    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.1.1")
    compile('com.oracle:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1')                       //oracle
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootStarterVersion}")
    testCompile("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.2.1.jre8")
}
```

Comment: This seems like an environment issue. When you run the jar locally, perhaps you are pointing to local resources that aren't found on the server ? Check the logs ? Compare both jar and see which files are different (if any). Compare environment variables. I see you use `spring.profile.active=user`, a guess would be that `application-user.properties` isn't found on the server (while being present locally) ?

Comment: @alexbt Actually, those 2 war file looks like having same contents(size is same). I make war file with `gradle build --refresh-dependencies --stacktrace -x test`. This command could be wrong? Also, `parallel` keyword can effect to this? (I got nothing to build but just one spring boot web application)

Comment: @alexbt upper one is build command and I ran application with `java -jar -Dspring.profile.active=user ABC.war` and I can see the profilename in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it does not matters with build environments. It was just a problem of code. Somebody override `Bean` again with null value.

anyway, thanks for helping me. (Especially, @alexbt)